# Why is my served site not rendering with this error?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

New to both Hugo & Blogdown. In a new R project called `personal-blog` I ran

`blogdown::new_site(theme = "lxndrblz/anatole")` and even after doing `blogdown::build_site()` and restarting the Rstudio I get the following

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t anatole -D -F --navigateToChanged
Serving the directory . at http://127.0.0.1:4321
Launched the hugo server in the background (process ID: 19844). To stop it, call blogdown::stop_server() or restart the R session.
```

None of the site formats properly. Supposed to look like [what you see here.](https://github.com/lxndrblz/anatole/) But none of the formatting is right on my local server. I don't see any of the CSS.

EDIT: Regarding the warning I got below with respect to `Rtools` -- it had something to do with MinGW and my version of R (4.0.3). When I was using my machine's default version R 3.6.1 nothing was working. I downloaded Rtools (this is not an R package from my understanding, it is something entirely different that you get from CRAN) [Rtools from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Once I reinstalled Rtools, added it to my system PATH and did it for both 32 & 64-bit versions, blogdown went back to working for me. Blogdown wasn't really the problem it was Rtools & MinGW not working nicely from what I can tell. Now I'll try to develop my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I have fixed this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/da1321100ffb9ee0f729ff060ba079ff7edb53cc) in the dev version of **blogdown**, which you may install with (remember to restart R):

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

The problem was because the theme used the Hugo function `absURL` for CSS files, which led to URLs of the form `http://localhost:port/path/to/css`, but the site was viewed from `http://127.0.0.1:port`, and the CORS issue of the browser prevented the CSS files from being loaded.

Comment: When I ran `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')` I got the following warning:

`WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.`
I will try installing it and seering what happens.

Comment: Rtools should not be needed to install the dev version of blogdown since this package doesn't contain code that needs to be compiled (such as C/C++). It seems you have solved your problem anyway, which is great!

Comment: Well I thought I had solved it. I appreciate your help. I know it isn't a blogdown issue though. I did `blogdown::install_hugo()` but then I got an error serving it `blogdown::serve_site()
Error in servr::server_config(..., baseurl = baseurl, hosturl = function(host) { : 
  unused argument (hosturl = function(host) {
    if (g == "hugo" && host == "127.0.0.1") "localhost" else host`

I know this is something going on with my laptop. Blogdown was working fine for me last week, but clearly I did something wrong. Need to put it away for a day - staring at it too long is confounding.

Comment: I'm happy to help! In theory, `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')` should do `remotes::install_github('yihui/servr')` automatically, but it seems it didn't. I don't know why, but you can run the second command manually, and restart R.

Comment: I had the same problem today. Your second command solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The fix I mentioned above has been available in the CRAN releases of blogdown for a couple of months now, so in theory, updating **blogdown** should just resolve the problem, and you don't need to switch to the URL `http://localhost` manually.